# Too long headers which contain the (too long) titles of the chapter

Tags: header-footer

I have some chapters (appendices) which have a very long title. The header which indicate the title of these chapter hence run out of the page. Is there any way to solve that?

An example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{rotating}


\lstnewenvironment{test}[1][]{%
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    autogobble=true,#1
    }%
}{}



\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
%
%% \usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%
%% this packaes are useful for nice algorithms
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}



\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
%\makesavenoteenv{table}


\begin{document}

\chapter[Examples of AAAAAAAAA BBBBBB and CCCCCCCCCCCC DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD EEEE FFFFF]{Examples of AAAAAAAAA BBBBBB and CCCCCCCCCCCC DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD EEEE FFFFF}
\label{cha:appendixH}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This code is not running out of the page@Aqqqq

Comment: The optional command of chapter (in square brackets) is designed to provide a short title to show in the table of contents and headers. Is there any specific reason to provide the full title there? why not write `\chapter[Various examples]{Examples of AAAAAAAAA BBBBBB and CCCCCCCCCCCC DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD EEEE FFFFF}`?

Comment: @BikiTeron it is in the headers. Put some `blindtext` to have the header on the next page ...

Comment: @Wiebke Thank you. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional commands to provide a short title to show in the relevant listings. Simply use `\chapter[Short title]{Very long and complicated title that will break the line in TOC and run over the page in headers}`. Note that this also works for all other headings (`part`, `section`, `subsection`).

It also works for the `\caption` in the same way. You can provide a short `caption` (maybe more like a headline as well) to show in the list of figures and list of tables.